# Escape speed of random walk on positive integers

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Let $\{X_i\}$ be the process with transition matrix
$$
p(X_{i + 1} = \ell | X_{i} = k) = \begin{cases}
q & \ell = k + 1 \quad \text{and} \quad k > 0 \\
1 - q & \ell = k - 1 \quad \text{and} \quad k > 0 \\
1 & \ell = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad k = 0 \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $X_0 = 0$ and $1/2 < q \leq 1$. This is a 1D biased random walk with a reflecting boundary at $0$. My question is

> How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n/n = 2q - 1$ a.s.?

If there was no reflecting boundary, the increments $\Delta X_{i} = X_{i} - X_{i - 1}$ would be i.i.d. and, since $E[\Delta X_{i}] = 2q - 1$, the limit follows immediately from the strong law. But in this case the increments aren't quite i.i.d. because sometimes the process might be at $0$. My thoughts are that, because there will be a last visit to $0$ almost surely, there must be some notion of the increments being "effectively" i.i.d. in the limit but I'm not sure how to formalize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it. It essentially follows from
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n > 0) &= 1 \\ 
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n = 0) &= 0
\end{align}
By Kingman's theorem, $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n/n = \lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n]/n = c$ a.s. for a $c > 0$. Therefore, letting $\Delta X_n = X_{n} - X_{n - 1}$ gives
\begin{align}
E[\Delta X_n] &= E[\Delta X_n| X_{n - 1} = 0] P(X_{n - 1} = 0) + E[\Delta X_n| X_{n - 1} > 0] P(X_{n - 1} > 0) \\
&= P(X_{n - 1} = 0) + (2q - 1) P(X_{n - 1} > 0) 
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_n}{n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\bigg[P(X_{n - 1} = 0) + (2q - 1) P(X_{n - 1} > 0)  \bigg] \quad \text{a.s.} \\ 
&= 2q - 1 \quad \text{a.s.}
\end{align}